# Implementation of ToLower function in C

Tags: c

I am writing my own implementation of ToLower(char *str) in C. But i am getting segmentation fault in the function. The function which i wrote is :

```
void ToLower(char *str)
{
    while(*str != '\0')
    {
        if(*str >=65 && *str<=90)
        {
            // It fails in the below assignment
            *str = *str + 32;
        }
        str++;
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you calling it? If called with a constant string  --  `ToLower("foo")` -- it should fail.

Comment: Are you calling it with a null terminated string?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why use `65` and `90` when `'A'` and `'Z'` are available and the meaning clearer?

Comment: You could change your function to create a new buffer and copy the characters over while changing the upper-case ones. Then return the new one. This does create issues in that you allocate a buffer in your ToLower method but have to remember to free up the allocated buffer in some other part of the code. It would be very easy to leave that out and eat up memory bit by bit as you use the method.

Comment: Not an answer - but the name of your function `ToLower()` suggests you are intending to implement a version of the ANSI C `tolower()`.  But clearly that is not your intention.  Perhaps a name change, such as StrToLower would fit your intentions better?

Comment: thanks everyone. I got my answer. Thanks Lee Meador. Thats the best way to do this, i agree

Answer (score 12):

You are almost certainly failing when you call it like:

```
int main(void)
{
    ToLower("HelloWorld");
    return 0;
}
```

This is because `"HelloWorld"` is a literal, constant string, and you cannot change its contents.

Try instead:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "HelloWorld";

    // Now str is your own local buffer, that you can modify.
    // It is initialized with the text, but that text can be changed.
    ToLower(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's generally considered to be good form to accept a length parameter in  functions that operate on strings. This way, if you pass in a string that's not null-terminated, the function won't loop past the end of the input.

You could step through the function call with a debugger, or add a print statement in the loop and see how many times it's iterating.

Comment: “It's generally considered to be good form to accept a length parameter in functions that operate on strings” Says who? It makes sense when manipulating data from an untrusted source, but it causes program boilerplate and arbitrary limitations in as many cases as it is useful.

Comment: He's implementing tolower(), which takes one argument and modifies the argument.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, if there's ever a chance the input might not be null-terminated, then it makes sense to pass in the length.

Comment: Are you proposing that every function that takes a null terminated string also provide a length parameter? That's crazy.

Comment: @CharlieBurns, my bad. Updated the answer. Thanks for pointing this out. If you know the function will only be called for null-terminated strings, then I don't see the need to pass a length parameter.

Comment: This sentance, "It's generally considered to be good form to accept a length parameter in functions that operate on strings." is simply not true. Lengths are passed when buffers are to filled not past a certain limit. That is not the case here. The C library functions that operate on strings take null terminated strings. Functions that could overwrite a buffer should take a length. That's the only time a length parameter makes any sense.

Comment: memcpy() et al, take lengths because they operate on raw bytes, not null terminated strings.

Comment: @ZachRattner:  You still need lengths, even if the string is null-terminated.   For detailed explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/06/28/10324808.aspx

Comment: The OP's stated objective, does not line up with his implementation.  The implementation suggests the desire is to change the entire string, clearly.  But his stated objective is to write a version of `tolower()`, which changes a ***single character*** per call.  [tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/).

Answer (score 0):

Although the name of your function `ToLower()` suggests you are re-writing the ANSI C version of `tolower()`, (i.e. changing one char from upper to lower case) your implementation suggests you really want an entire string to be changed.  Perhaps the name `StrToLower()` is what you are really intending? (i.e. change the entire string). If that is the case, the following code illustrates.  (if you really want to re-write `tolower()`, it should really be a different question, with a prototype similar to the C version, and changing only one char per call)

*This answer assumes because of the tag "c" in your question, that  you are not wanting the .NET version of `String.ToLower()` (which DOES convert a string). If this is a wrong assumption, disregard my rants.*

This method will work with a `char *str="STRING";`, or with a constant string (`"STRING"`) as an argument.
***[Expanded]*** Include an implementation of ToLower, in case that is what OP really wanted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char * StrToLower(char *str) ;
int toLower(int chr);

int main(void)
{
    char lowered[] = "UPPER to Lower"; 

    sprintf(lowered, "%s",StrToLower(lowered));
    printf("%s\n", lowered); //works with a variable buffer argument

    lowered[0]=0;//clear the buffer

    sprintf(lowered, "%s",StrToLower("UPPER to Lower")); 
    printf("%s\n", lowered); //also works with a literal string argument

    getchar();//view results
    return 0;
}

char * StrToLower(char *str)
{
    char *pNew1 = str;
    char *pNew2 = str;

    if(str != NULL) //NULL ?
    {
        if(strlen(str) != 0) //"" ?
        {
            while(*pNew1)
            {
                *pNew2 = toLower(*pNew1); 
                ++pNew2;
                ++pNew1;
            }
            *pNew2 = '\0';
            return str;// return changed string
        }              // and prevent returning null to caller
    }
    return "";//Will never get here for non-null input argurment
}   

int toLower(int chr)//touches only one character per call
{
    return (chr >='A' && chr<='Z') ? (chr + 32) : (chr);    
}
```

***Results:*** (answering Roland's comment)
[image]

Comment: Your code does *not* work when called with a string literal. Besides, what is `<ansi_c.h>`? And why do you return `""` from StrToLower? And what about character sets where there are non-letters between `A` and `Z`?

Comment: @RolandIllig - ***1)*** I just verified it _does_ work when called with a string literal, just as it did over a year ago, as long as the string literal does not overwrite the original buffer size of `lowered`.  ***2)*** I return `""` in the event a null argument is passed into the function.  If not, execution flow never gets there.    ***3)*** anci_c.h is an ANSI C header collector I used.  I guess if you really had to find an issue with my answer, that would be it.  You can get away with using stdio.h in its place with this particular example.  (which I have edited into the example)

Answer (score -2):

for safe variable you can use the following prototype:

```
void ToLower(const char *str)
```

Comment: tolower() by definition changes the given string in place.

Comment: Oh, i didn't its body , yes you say correctly, but it don't safe, your primative string should be change...

Comment: @CharlieBurns - the `tolower()` I am familiar with takes a single character, and returns a single character, usually with something like `int tolower(int chr);` as a prototype.

Comment: @ryyker - What was I thinking? You are right. I saw the code, and then probably thought about the python routine by that name.

Comment: @CharlieBurns - You were evidently not the only one.  :)